# Image Server - Creating list of URL and Filename

Tags: csv, google-drive-api, shopify

I'm in the process of uploading products to Shopify through csv. I have a load of image in Google Drive with public links but they're creating errors. Two questions I guess. First, can I make this work keeping images in Drive and, if so, what resources can you provide that will aid me in accessing the API for url and filename? Second, if not, what's the best process/system for hosting images and exporting the image URl and filename into a spreadsheet, so I can then add to csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what sort of error you are getting but the general way to link a  image from an external source is using the API. From the docs:

```
POST /admin/products/#{id}/images.json
{
  "image": {
    "src": "http://example.com/rails_logo.gif" 
  }
}
```

However Shopify won't serve that image from Google Drive. When an image is linked via the src Shopify uploads it and distributes it to its Content-Delivery-Network. When loading a Google Drive image Shopify tries to upload it but GD sends at least one round of redirects which Shopify won't follow.

Your best bet would be to: load the image; base64 encode it; upload the image content using the API. The sample below shows how to do this with Node.js

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var cred = new Buffer("APIKey:APIPassword").toString('base64');
var headers = {
    Authorization: "Basic " + cred,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
};
var options = {
    host: 'mystore.myshopify.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/admin/products/1934429697/images.json',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
};

function sendImageFS() {
    // Setup the request.  The options parameter is
    // the object we defined above.
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        var responseString = '';
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            responseString += data;

        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log(responseString);
            var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        // TODO: handle error.
        console.log(e);
    });
    fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\Brett\\Desktop\\whitebird_500.jpg', function(err, data) {
            var base64data = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
            var imagePayload = {
                image: {
                    attachment: base64data,
                    filename: 'whitebird.jpg'
                }
            };
            req.write(JSON.stringify(imagePayload));
            req.end();
    });
}
sendImageFS();
```

Comment: IOW no. You cannot add google drive images via CSV. If you want to add mages via CSV you'd need to save all your image files to some directly (no-redirects) available public url.

Comment: I found a rather fascinating workaround for this. Shopify cannot download images from a link that is protected by user level authentication. To get this to work, I place all the images inside a public (no not free) folder of Dropbox and get the files' public links. This way it works.

Comment: @HymnZ dropbox no longer works. "As of March 15, 2017 the Public folder in your Dropbox account has been converted into a standard folder.  " https://www.dropbox.com/help/16

Comment: @eddyparkinson You can use Shopify's "Files" folder for this purpose as well. It's located at `Admin->Settings->Files`